# Marginal Risk Contribution Implementation Questions

Tags: portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory

Sorry if this is too obvious to you. The marginal risk contribution mentioned here is the same as in this post [Marginal Risk Contribution Formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37878/marginal-risk-contribution-formula) .

I understand the concepts and derivation on the formula. But I got some questions from some legacy codes I'm working on. Original writer isn't available anymore. Will appreciate if anyone can shed some lights.

Calculation from the codes is pretty much following the formula mentioned in above link. There are two particularities.

1. The portfolio is a long-short portfolio.
2. The calculation uses each symbol's sided US dollar notional as weight $w_{i}$.

My questions are:

1. What's the unit of calculated results $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$? Notice that the weights used in calculating $\sigma$ are also the sided US dollar notional. I'm guessing since the unit of $\sigma$ is US dollar notional, weight $w_{i}$ is US dollar notional, so $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ is unitless?
2. What does it mean when $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ is positive or negative? My guess is since it's partial derivative, if $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}} > 0$, then symbol $i$ is risk contributor and if $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}} < 0$, then symbol $i$ is risk reducer? However, I noticed the calculated results have all negative $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ for short positions and positive $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ for long positions. This seems odd. There seems nothing obviously wrong with the calculation. Just wondering if there is some conceptual things deeper than what I realized.
3. Is it proper to use each symbol $i$'s sided dollar notional as weights $w_{i}$ in $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$? If not, what should be used for $w_{i}$?

Thank you a lot for some clarifications.

Comment: The negative sign of $\frac{\delta\sigma}{\delta w_i}$ for short positions makes sense to me: if the (negative) $w_i$ is increased, i.e. moves towards zero, the risk decreases. To cut risk of a short you have to buy the thing.  I have not worked with MRC for L/S portfolios but this approach seems reasonable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!

Still wondering about the part of unit... The numbers I saw is on the range of 0.001 to 0.0001.  That's when I wonder about their units. My guess is since $w_{i}$ is notional, this gives $\sigma$ as notional. Then $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ is unitless.  Is this reasoning right?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is a pure number. I believe the scale is related to the size of the average position, my first thought was 0.001 means 1000 equal sized long positions, but now I am not sure that's true. I am curious what all the positive MRC's add up to, what all the negatives ones add up to and the overall sum.

Comment: Thanks again for your insights! Just to illustrate. A portfolio has long \$120M, short \$54M.  Long $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ has sum 0.48, average 0.025. Short $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{w_{i}}}$ has sum -0.02, average -0.01